# python selenium default chrome path format

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, operating-system

I'm trying to format the path to chrome profile data but it's not working. However, it works perfectly fine when I print the path with  or without formatting and chrome isn't opening with my existing profile.

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

options = Options()
profile_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), 'Google', 'Chrome', 'User Data')
print('format:{}'.format(profile_path))
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir={}".format(profile_path))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't `os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')` that you're supposed to use? I don't believe that Chrome stores data in the `"APPDATA"` folder.

Comment: @HampusLarsson Mb  it worked thanks for reply. I thought it would be appdata  cuz  thats where i usually access data drives didnt know that thank you again. Its frustrating to know its actually that simple to solve i spend 2 hours looking for a solution